# Set the meta table for the lua meta table

Tags: lua, metatable

The __index of the table originally set a meta table, and the actual access is to the function under this meta table.

`setmetatable(flatTbl, {__index = metaTbl}`

I want to access the function of the same name of the meta table when the field of the table is not accessible, but I have used two methods without success

```
function FlatBufferTools:SetMeta(flatTbl)
    setmetatable(flatTbl, {
        __index = function(tbl, key)
            metaTbl = getmetatable(tbl).__index
            return metaTbl[key](metaTbl)
        end
    })
end

function FlatBufferTools:SetMeta2(flatTbl)
    metaTbl = getmetatable(flatTbl).__index
    setmetatable(metaTbl, {
        __index = function(tbl, key)
            return tbl[key](tbl)
        end
    })
end
```

The first method is to reset the `__index` of the table, but the `metaTbl` that i get is a function

The second method is to set `__index` to the table's meta table(`metaTbl`), but the setmetatable function skips it

I checked the `metaTbl` and there is no `__metatable`

Comment: sorry, already modified @Piglet

Comment: what is metaTbl befor you run those functions? and how do you call those functions?

Comment: metaTbl is a lua table with some function, I want use tbl.field to call metaTbl:field()

Answer (score 1):

> I want to access the function of the same name of the meta table when
> the field of the table is not accessible

```
local meta = { myFunc = function () print("metatable here") end }
meta.__index = meta

local a = setmetatable({}, meta)
a.myFunc()
```

`a.myFunc` is nil so you'll call `meta.myFunc`

Answer (score 0):

You know the `table` library?
Lets make the `table` functions "not accessible" to `a` and raise them to methods...

```
> a = setmetatable({}, {__index = table})
> for i = 1, 10 do a:insert(i) end
> print(a:concat('\n'))
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
>
```